# How can i set keywords or (similar information) per page on pdf?

Tags: pdf, adobe, metadata

i have a pdf it has almost 300-400 pages.I want to set information about per page.

Ex :

```
(Information will be hidden)

For page 4 = Information : history books
For page 5 = Information : history books
For page 6 = Information : history books

For page 7 = Information : biology books
For page 8 = Information : biology books
For page 9 = Information : biology books

.
.
.
```

And then i can extract pages easyly.

thx for ur helps

Answer (score 2):

You are probably looking at a toolkit that will allow you to set some metadata within a PDF file. The most commonly used is probably [XMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Metadata_Platform). The wiki also provides a list of toolkits that work with XMP. Adobe provides a [toolkit](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/xmp.html) free of charge under the BSD license. You may be interested in checking that out.

Comment: Can i find a sample about it for C# ?

Comment: The link I posted contains a host of information. A quick glance revealed this: <http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/xmp/pdfs/ActionScriptAccessToXMP.pdf> Did you go through the page? I'm sure you'll find a few samples over there.

Comment: Also adding a hidden text to page is possible ?

Comment: D'oh! The link was edited out! Can you check out the link I posted?